# FF SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: json, security, jquery

My code suddenly stopped working after I updated ti IE9 , both IE9 and FF don't work.

FF gives me 
"SecurityError: The operation is insecure" on the line
`data: JSON.stringify(someVar),`

When I am doing jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myPage/myMethod",
        data: JSON.stringify(someVar),        
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
...});
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what can I do to prevent this? It appears that it's trying to post to a different domain but since this is not the case, why is this suddenly a security issue?

Comment: Please close. I had an unrelated error. Thank you.